# Change objective C anonymous function to non anonymous one

Tags: objective-c, anonymous-function

I'm a newbie in objective c working on swift.io and trying to convert its anonymous callbacks to non-anonymous function.

basically trying to convert

```
[self.Socket on:@"connect" callback:^(NSArray* data, SocketAckEmitter* ack) {
    NSLog(@"socket connected");
}];
```

to something like

```
 [self.Socket on:@"connect" callback:connectTestCallback];
```

i tried defining a following function which i'll call

```
- (void) connectTestCallback:(NSArray* )data withAck:(SocketAckEmitter *)ack
{
    NSLog(@"socket connected");
}
```

But i'm not sure if thats how i'm supposed to define it, and have no idea how to call it. I've tried calling it as callback:@selector(connectTestCallback) but obviously that didn't work.

Following is definition of "on" function.

```
- (void)on:(NSString * __nonnull)event callback:(void (^ __nonnull)(NSArray * __nonnull, SocketAckEmitter * __nonnull))callback;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "anonymous function" is a block building a closure. In contrast to functions and methods a closure stores its creation environment, so you can access this inside the code. But if the actual arguments are enough data to do what you want to do, you can simply send a message to `self` to execute the "named" method:

```
[self.Socket on:@"connect" callback:^(NSArray* data, SocketAckEmitter* ack) 
{
 [self connectTestCallback:data withAck:ack];
}];
```

Comment: yea going to use this now. on side note there needs to be a ] after ack before ;